# Dropping MongoDB database or its tables using JPA (Hibernate) in Play Framework

Tags: java, mongodb, jpa, playframework, hibernate-ogm

I'm trying to drop either the database or the table at the end of an integration test so that the next run will have a clean database to work with. I'm working with Java in the Play framework and we're using Mongo DB with Hibernate OGM.

I've set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` property in the `persistence.xml` file as shown below.

```
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
```

In my integration test there is an @After method in which I explicitly call close on the EntityManagerFactory via `JPA.em().getEntityManagerFactory().close();`. At that point when I go back to my MongoDB all the tables are still there intact with the new rows still persisted.

Can someone point to where I'm going wrong or what I'm missing? My understanding is that the combination of the two should drop the table/database after the EMF is closed.

Comment: did you find the solution?

Comment: @ObaidMaroof unfortunately we never found a solution to drop the database. We ended up either dropping or deleting individual tables instead from my recollection which was a little tedious when new tables needed to be cleared out.